# NPM - command failed: git -c core

Tags: react-native, npm

Buenas tardes se me presenta el siguiente error al tratar de instalar lo siguiente:

```
npm install react-native-router-flux
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue iniciar el proyecto con una version anterior de react-native

```
react-native --version="0.55.4" Project
```

y utilizar **npm en su version 5.10.0**

Answer (score 0):

para instalar react-native-router-flux deberias usar el siguientes comando  igualmente mira si tienes instalado npm,suele suceder que porque no lo tienes instalado o tienes una vieja version te suele dar problemas,mira si tienes instalado npm la version : npm. 6.1.0:

```html
   npm i react-native-router-flux --save
```

para mas informacion mira este sitio:[tutorial para instalar react-native-router-flux - esta en ingles](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/README3.md)

y [documentacion oficial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: no funciona pero gracias

Comment: que raro, si en la misma documentacion de npm acerca ese paquete dice este comando: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-router-flux   posiblemente sea tu proyecto o sistema operativo o que no instalastes bien react native

Comment: no lo se probare reinstalando todo desde 0

Comment: @Revsky01 Recuerda cuando comentes en una respuesta, indicar porque no funciona. Si en este caso es porque es el mismo comando, indicaselo a quien responde por favor.